# filament php : How to add a dropdown menu to the left side bar (navigation)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

i'm using filament php and i want to add a dropdown menu to the left side bar of my admin panel,
in the documentation there's only how to add a link to the navigation
any idea on how i can do it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answer you're looking for is in the docs here:

https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/navigation#registering-custom-navigation-items

This is how I would do it inside of the "app/Providers/appServiceProvider.php" file

```php
<?php

use Filament\Facades\Filament;
use Filament\Navigation\NavigationGroup;
use Filament\Navigation\NavigationItem;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Filament::serving(function () {

            // First we register a custom navigation group
            Filament::registerNavigationGroups(
                [
                    NavigationGroup::make()
                        ->label('Shop')
                        ->icon('heroicon-s-shopping-cart')
                        ->collapsed(),
                ]
            );

            // Then we register the links that will go into that navigation group
            Filament::registerNavigationItems(
                [
                    NavigationItem::make('My Custom Link 1')
                        ->url('https://filament.pirsch.io', shouldOpenInNewTab: true)
                        ->icon('heroicon-o-link')
                        ->group('Shop')
                        ->sort(1),
                    NavigationItem::make('My Custom Link 2')
                        ->url('https://filament.pirsch.io', shouldOpenInNewTab: true)
                        ->icon('heroicon-o-link')
                        ->group('Shop')
                        ->sort(2),
                ]
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Good luck on your laravel journey!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i had already tried this solution
i think that the NavigationItem can be only of type LINK
and i want to add a select tag with options